# Script to convert MSF 4.2 to Microsoft SCRUM 1.0

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to migrate my project MSF 4.2 for Microsoft SCRUM 1.0. I'm already using the tool TFS Integration and I already created an empty SCRUM 1.0 project. Now I need the script to migrate the project. Does anyone have the xml script conversion from MSF 4.2 to Microsoft SCRUM  1.0? 
Thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TFS Integration Mapper tool](http://tfsintegrationmapper.codeplex.com/) to build the necessary XML.